# How to write the latex for the L^2 on an arrow?

Tags: symbols

This post uses this math equation

[image]

How to write the latex for the L^2 on an arrow?

Comment: @Lukas your link is already a duplicate

Comment: `F_n(x) \xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle \: L^2\:} F(x)` I think it looks best with a little extra space and an even smaller font size

Comment: Kind user you can try, also, this code: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$F_n(x)\overset{\scriptstyle L^2}{\to}F(x)$
\end{document}`. It is very important to try to read any guide for LaTeX :-). The tag, for my humble opinion, is off-topic.

Comment: @BambOo I think that is still not the right duplicate. `\rightarrow` and `\Rightarrow` are very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \[F_n(x)\underrightarrow{L^2}F(x)\] % answer by Sango
 \[F_n(x)\overset{\scriptstyle L^2}{\to}F(x)\] % answer by Sebastiano
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `$\xrightarrow{L^2}$` from the `amsmath` package is a better choice in terms of spacing in my opinion.

Comment: That might be true. But this is also an answer for the question. I don't understand why this is downvoted.

Comment: @Sango Your output (code) is different from the image of the user. It is very important to put a MWE (with all the packages used). **Addendum**: I have given trusted you. Enter an MWE.

Comment: That also may be, but it answers the question on how to write L^2 above an arrow.

Comment: The arrow should be higher, just like when one types `\rightarrow`. Pushing it down there is wrong.

Comment: Added MWE, took @Sebastiano s answer from the comments and added that also for comparison. It does look better.

Comment: looks a lot better now, I removed the downvote